# Checking for a loop in an un-directed tree graph python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to develop a python program to check if there is a loop in the graph when a new line is added.

I am storing different lines in a list ordered by shortest length first, and the lines are a class:

```
class Line():
def __init__(self,node1,node2,length):
    self.node1 = node1
    self.node2 = node2
    self.length = int(length)
    self.drawn = False
```

And the nodes are stored in a list:

```
nodes = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
```

When my program has run it stores the route as a list:

```
route = [class(Line),class(Line)...]
```

What i want it to do is to check that when a new line is added that it does not form a cycle. I plan to use a method inside of a bigger class:

something like:

```
def check_loop(new_line,graphs):
    add new line to graph
    if there is a loop in graphs:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

*(sorry this is one of my first posts so the format is rubbish)*

Comment: Are you trying to make a tree or a more general graph?

Comment: I am trying to connect all of the nodes in a graph in the shortest possible tree

Comment: So you are trying to construct the minimum spanning tree?

Comment: Ok so then using Prim's algorithm or something similar you shouldn't have to worry about making cycles accidentally as any tree with a cycle in it isn't a tree.

Comment: Will do, thanks @NickChapman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify if a cycle is created in a tree is pretty simple, all you need to do is pick a node and then breadth first search the entire tree from that node. If any node has been visited before by the time you reach it, then you know that there is a cycle because there was an alternative path that reached that node beside the one that you have taken.